# OS X Keychains: 32 to 64 bit

Tags: objective-c, macos, 64-bit, keychain

I recently switched my application from 32 bit to 64 bit on Mac OS X. The only problem that I am having now is some users are complaining that their existing keychains are not being saved anymore and they cannot create new ones. Is there any reason the keychain service would stop working after such a switch? The actual code to process the keychains never changed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without looking at the code in question, but since the keychain APIs are C and not Objective C, you may be running into some problems with the passing of some UInt32's that may previously have been coerced from 'unsigned int' or 'int'.

I'd check through your calls to all of the Sec* routines, and look for signs of problems with type coercion.